# Issue when indexing footnotes (print as syntax error)

Tags: footnotes, indexing

Edit: @footnotetext issue solved. Remains this one :

I have an issue with indexing footnotes.

My footnotes indexing print as syntax errors; the Xelatex output does not print my footnotes as such, but in plain text.

Here is a typical exemple of the code I use (Ii is the name of one out of two index files):

```
L'acquisition par les Africains de capital scolaire dans des universités
de Grande-Bretagne ou d'Amérique perturbait les hiérarchies 
coloniales\footcite[Le cas en Afrique francophone des diplômés de
l'école William Ponty\index[Ii]{William Ponty, école} en est 
particulièrement exemplaire :][]{Jezequel2007}.
```

Can one tell me what's wrong with that?

EDIT: MWE added :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{xunicode} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage{french} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xspace} 
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s index.ist, title=Individus Lieux Pratiques et Institutions, name=Ii]
\makeindex[options=-s index.ist, title=Auteurs et Concepts]
\indexsetup{level=\section*, toclevel=\section*, noclearpage}

\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=verbose-trad2, bibstyle=verbose, singletitle=true, indexing=cite]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio}
\begin{document}
L'acquisition par les Africains de capital scolaire dans des universités de Grande-Bretagne ou d'Amérique perturbait les hiérarchies coloniales\footcite[Le cas en Afrique francophone des diplômés de l'école William Ponty\index[Ii]{William Ponty, école} en est particulièrement exemplaire :][]{Jezequel2007}.

\chapter*{Index}                                  
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\emph{Index}}

\printindex[Ii]
\printindex         
\end{document}
```

Everything worked perfectly until I started to index my document...

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: when i tried processing your example, i didn't get the `file ended` error, but the file `Ii.idx` was empty.  there seems to be a syntax error in the input for `\footcite`, but i can't find where that is defined to check it.

Comment: Same intuition that the system reacts as if there was a syntax error, as the compilation output (an aborted pdf file) clearly displays : it works as if I had forgotten a bracket. Strangely enough,  some footnote indexation work, and some do not, it seems...So that's weird to me.

Comment: ok, so the @footnote text error was a bracket missing when I removed one of my index commands. Edited the pb consequently. Remains the main issue : why does the indexing of my footnotes print as syntax errors ?

Comment: Use `\footcite[Le ... Ponty{\index[Ii]{William Ponty, école}} ...}` with an additional pair of braces around the index command, because the `]` after `Ii` otherwise confuses LaTeX when it has to decide where the optional argument to `\footcite` ends.

Comment: Seems to work fine now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in how optional arguments are scanned: the optional argument is whatever goes from `[` to the first `]` at the same brace level; in your case, the `]` after `Ii` confuses LaTeX so it absorbs the wrong optional argument to `\footcite`. Solution: type an additional pair of braces.

```
L'acquisition par les Africains de capital scolaire dans des universités
de Grande-Bretagne ou d'Amérique perturbait les hiérarchies 
coloniales\footcite[Le cas en Afrique francophone des diplômés de
l'école William Ponty{\index[Ii]{William Ponty, école}} en est
particulièrement exemplaire :][]{Jezequel2007}.
```